# MVC How to abort method execution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method, that I want to abort its execution if some condifion takes place.

the simplest scenario would be

```
public bool myFlag = true;

public bool MyMethod(/*args*/)
{
    if(myFlag)
    {
       //do some stuff #1
    }
    else
        return false;

    if(myFlag)
    {
       //do some stuff #2
    }
    else
        return false;

    //etc
}
```

but the problem is, my mythod has so much code inside, and I don't want to check `myFlag` in each line because the code will be messed up and hard to understand. I'm wondering how to simplify that scenario, but I don't have any ideas.

I'm thinking about to put that method to the separate `Thread`, but the UI must wait until the operation completes and also that metod has I/O operations inside (if it matters)

Comment: Confirm to me, to check if I understood. `MyMethod`will be executed in a thread and `myFlag` can be set in another thread?

Comment: no, I don't use Thread class right now, it's only a guess

Comment: But if your variable `myFlag` is not volatile (can be changed out the context), why you need to check it more than once?

Comment: because the method must abort its execution no matter where the compiler is inside that method. If I check the myFlag only at 1st line inside that method and the compiler is at e.g 10th line, the execution will go further and won't be aborted

Comment: So `myFlag` must be being set by some of the calls inside `MyMethod`. If you consider each point where `myFlag` may change as the end of a "step", what else do the steps have in common? If you can convert it into a loop structure, you will only need `while(myFlag)`.

Comment: yep, but if I pu the whole code inside while(myFlag) the myFlag will be checked after the all code execution

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use the [observer pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx)

Comment: Mighty complicated for what he wants

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle this kind of requirements: basically, I take the method apart and create many sub-methods and then use exceptions to regulate the flow (I find this the best compromise between functionality and readability).

It looks like this:

```
private void performFirstStep(/*args*/)
{
    //do stuff, throw if something goes wrong
}
private void performSecondStep(/*args*/)
{
    //do stuff, throw if something goes wrong
}

public bool MyMethod(/*args*/)
{
    try
    {
        // each method is supposed to represent a single Unit Of Work
        performFirstStep(/*args*/);
        performSecondStep(/*args*/);
        performThirdStep(/*args*/);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) // I usually craft a custom exc. type to use here
    {
        // overly simplified catch block: you'll probably want
        // to *not* swallow the exceptions coming from the inside methods...
        // lots of possibilities here to easen debug
        return false;
    }
}
```

You could also make the methods `bool` and use their return value but you need to try-catch anyway so you might as well leverage it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding, is this not the exact same as your example, but with a single condition check:

```
public bool MyMethod(/*args*/)
{
     if(!myFlag)
          return false;

     //Rest of glorious code!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting a flag, simply return from the method when you detect the abort condition. If that still leaves an unwieldy method, the problem is likely to be that there's too much code in it! Identify units of work and refactor them into separate sub-methods.